# What is the name of Ancient Egyptian "water jousting"

Tags: egyptian

I have come across a form of combat from ancient Egypt called 'water jousting'. Does anyone know the actual Egyptian term for this, or any other ancient Egyptian terms for things like wrestling, which the greeks called pale (πάλη)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Archeologists call it "Egyptian Fisherman Jousting", an aquatic combat sport practiced in ancient Egypt. Modern knowledge of this sport comes from studying ancient Egyptian tomb reliefs.

[image]

Though the Egyptian reliefs that depict fisherman jousting don’t appear in contexts of war or battle, many of these depictions appear to be quite malicious and violent. This leaves the impression that the activity pictured may not have been entertainment, but rather something more aggressive, such as battles for fishing territory.

We do not know what the Ancient Egyptians called this. If you *really* want an Egyptian name, we could infer:

(wHa-w-aach[a]), the  can mean both "to row" and "to fight", the  indicates a plural of  (fisherman)

Comment: So it would translate out to "fishermen jousting" and would phonetically be pronounced "whah wuh ahch"?

Comment: Something like that, we cannot be sure of the vowels though.